# Swift: Retrieve a 2D array from Parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am new to programming. Just started a month back. I am working on a swift project and wanted to retrieve data from Parse.

I have two options, either have the data in the form or a 1D array or I can have it in the form of 2D array. I am having problem retrieving both the arrays. I cannot attach a picture as I don't have ratings. So will explain my database as below:
Class: FruitQuantityMatrix
Columns: ObjectID, Sr.Number, fruitName, fruitQuantityEachDay.
Rows: Apple, Orange, Cherry, Banana, Grape, Guava, Kiwi

Otherwise, if possible, I can also use 2D data to retrieve. In that case the data would be something like the Matrix below. But I am thinking it's better to use 1D array. But for learning purpose I want to understand how it works in Parse.

```
var QMatrix:[[String]] = [
        ["11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],
        ["10","22","23","24","25","26","27"],
        ["31","32","33","34","35","36","37"],
        ["41","42","43","44","45","46","47"],
        ["51","52","53","54","55","56","57"],
        ["61","62","63","64","65","66","67"],
        ["71","72","73","74","75","76","77"]
    ]
```

I tried to use the code which I was using to retrieving the image, but it is not working. Code is as below:

```
var imageResources : Array<UIImage> = []     
func loadQuantity() {

        var query = PFQuery(className: "FruitQuantityMatrix")
        query.orderByDescending("serialNo")

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({(objects:[AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) in
            if(error == nil){

                self.getQuantityData(objects as [PFObject])
            }
            else{
                println("Error in retrieving \(error)")
            }

        })//findObjectsInBackgroundWithblock - end


    }

    func getQuantityData(objects: [PFObject]) {
        for object in objects {

            let qty = object["fruitQuantityEachDay"] as PFObject
            println(qty)

            qty.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
                (quantityData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if (error == nil) {
                    let fruitQuantityEachDay = self.quantityResources.append(fruitQuantityEachDay!)
                    println(fruitQuantityEachDay!)
                }

            })//getDataInBackgroundWithBlock - end

        }//for - end
    }
```

I would appreciate if you could provide me the code. But would prefer a short explanation as I want to do the programming on my own. Every other place (facebook community) I have posted, they need money to teach me. I don't have money and want to learn. So any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what you want help with tbh.

Comment: @Arbitur I have stored an array of fruit quantity available each day in my Parse database. So I want to get all the rows containing "fruitQuantityEachDay" in my app in the array format. Ex: Row values in Apple row: ["11", "10", "31", "41", "51", 61"] in the column "fruitQuantityEachDay".

Comment: So you want to add all the info in a 2d array so it looks like a table? Ex: an array where every index (row) contains another array with all the row data?

Comment: https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#top/iOS Parse  documents

Comment: @Arbitur Well, I just want to add the database created in Parse (consisting of Row: Fruit names with Column: Containing an array of 'fruit quantity' available each day. Fruit (Ex: Apple) = QuantityEachDay (Ex: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]). In this, on Monday quantity of Apple available is 1, Tuesday 2, Wednesday 3.. and so on till Sunday 7. This quantity array is of type String. So basically I want to retrieve a string array of quantity of fruits available for all fruits. Sorry, I am not able to attach a photo as SO is not allowing me.

Comment: You can upload to imgur and share the link

Comment: @Arbitur http://imgur.com/Ce3eYyq This is the link of my database in parse. And Thank you so much Arbitur for following up with me. No one seems to help as they might thing I am asking some stupid question. I wish they understand that I am really new and working all on my own. It's easy for them, not for a complete newbie in programming. Thanks again.

Comment: Ive never used Parse database, but Im willing to help you with my 5 years of knowledge :)

Comment: What are you able to retreive from the database so far?

Comment: @Arbitur I can retrieve an array of images stored in my database. Using the solution of this code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764618/swift-image-retrieving-from-parse-sdk-getting-crashed. With this we can retrieve the images in an array. But I want to retrieve a string of array.

Comment: https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-retrieving/iOS This tells you how to retreive data from Parse database

Answer (score 1):

As seen in the [Docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-retrieving/iOS) you retreive data from the database using this method:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"FruitQuantityMatrix")

query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("some_id") { object, error in
    if error == nil {
        println(object)
    } 
    else {
        println(error)
    }
}
```

And to access the values inside `object` you treat it like a `Dictionary`:

```
let name = object["fruitName"] as String
let arr = object["fruitQuantityEachDay"] as [String]
```

If you want all or a specific row without using the id then use this instead:

```
query.whereKey("fruitName", equalTo: "Apple") // Dont use this if you want to retreive all rows

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { object, error in 
    let name = object[rowIndex]["fruitName"] as String
}
```

Comment: I was able to get this in my variable: fruitQuantityArray = [[(
    51,
    52,
    53,
    54,
    55,
    56,
    57
)], [(
    41,
    42,
    43,
    44,
    45,
    46,
    47
)], [(
    31,
    32,
    33,
    34,
    35,
    36,
    37
)], [(
    21,
    22,
    23,
    24,
    25,
    26,
    27
)], [(
    11,
    10,
    31,
    41,
    51,
    61,
    71
)]]
Which is JSON. Do you know how to convert it to something to an array of string?... Like this [["51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57"], ["41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47"] and so on.....]]?

Comment: Thats not a json, it looks like an array of arrays printed out in the console.

Comment: try print out (fruitQuantityArray as [[String]])[0][0] and see what you get.

Comment: I just got it working. I used SwiftyJSON to retrieve the object. let  myArray = JSON(object["fruitQuantityEachDay"]!!) did all the magic! After this I just used self.quantityResourcesQuantity.append("\(myArray)") and my array was in the variable 'quantityResourcesQuantity' exactly as I needed in the form of an 2D Array of string. Thank you so much for supporting me and following up with me.

Comment: Good it worked out for you :) If above was helping you plase upvote it and accept :)

Comment: I am so sorry, stackoverflow is not allowing me to do that. It says that only members with 15 rating can up vote. I just have 1 :(